# How to use sum of absolute difference condition in python pulp?

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I have been looking up similar posts regarding absolute value condition in linear programming, and trying the proposed solutions. However, I am still struggling to make my pulp setup work in python.

I post the simplified code here. Specifically, in "nearer constraint" below, I want to impose the *sum of absolute difference* to be smaller than some threshold, "sum(df['diff_orig'])". The posted code works but this is with just a sum difference *not with absolute difference*.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

J

````
import pandas as pd
import pulp

# initialize data
nav = 1000
data = [['A', 0.2], ['B', 0.4], ['C', 0.1], ['D', 0.3], ['cash', 0.0]]

# create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['asset', 'w_star'])
df['prccd'] = [17, 21, 119, 49, None]
df['q_tilde'] = [11, 19, 0, 6, None]
df['val'] = df.prccd * df.q_tilde
df.loc[df.asset == 'cash', 'val'] = nav - sum(df.loc[~df.val.isna(), 'val'])
df['w_act'] = df.val / sum(df.val)
df['diff_orig'] = abs(df.w_star - df.w_act)
df = df.set_index('asset')

# manipulate cash
dfnc = df[df.index != 'cash']

# create variables and model
dq = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("dq", dfnc.index, cat='Integer', lowBound=0)
mod = pulp.LpProblem("CashReduction", pulp.LpMinimize)

# objective function
mod += nav - sum([dq[i] * dfnc.loc[i, 'prccd'] + dfnc.loc[i, 'q_tilde'] * dfnc.loc[i, 'prccd'] for i in dfnc.index])

# lower bounds:
for i in dfnc.index:
    mod += dq[i] >= 0

# budget constraint
mod += sum([dq[i] * dfnc.loc[i, 'prccd'] for i in dfnc.index]) <= df.loc['cash', 'val']

# nearer constraint
mod += sum(
    [dfnc.loc[i, 'w_star'] - (dq[i] * dfnc.loc[i, 'prccd'] + dfnc.loc[i, 'q_tilde'] * dfnc.loc[i, 'prccd']) / nav
     for i in dfnc.index]) <= sum(df['diff_orig'])

# individual diff cannot be bigger than 3%
for i in dfnc.index:
    mod += (dfnc.loc[i, 'w_star'] -
            (dq[i] * dfnc.loc[i, 'prccd'] + dfnc.loc[i, 'q_tilde'] * dfnc.loc[i, 'prccd']) / nav) <= 0.03
for i in dfnc.index:
    mod += (dfnc.loc[i, 'w_star'] -
            (dq[i] * dfnc.loc[i, 'prccd'] + dfnc.loc[i, 'q_tilde'] * dfnc.loc[i, 'prccd']) / nav) >= -0.03

# solve model
mod.solve()

# output solution
for i in dfnc.index:
    print(i, dq[i].value())```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to introduce an additional indexed variable to do this.  ABS is non-linear, so the typical way to handle one ABS function is to introduce *one* variable and make that variable greater than the pos value and greater than the negation of the target of ABS like so:

```
if we are working with |x - y|...
g > x - y
g > -(x - y)
```

in your case you have an ABS function for each element to be summed, so you can just extend the above by creating a new variable, indexed by the same things you want to sum, and working with that...

```
import pandas as pd
import pulp

# initialize data
nav = 1000
data = [['A', 0.2], ['B', 0.4], ['C', 0.1], ['D', 0.3], ['cash', 0.0]]

# create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['asset', 'w_star'])
df['prccd'] = [17, 21, 119, 49, None]
df['q_tilde'] = [11, 19, 0, 6, None]
df['val'] = df.prccd * df.q_tilde
df.loc[df.asset == 'cash', 'val'] = nav - sum(df.loc[~df.val.isna(), 'val'])
df['w_act'] = df.val / sum(df.val)
df['diff_orig'] = abs(df.w_star - df.w_act)
df = df.set_index('asset')
print(df)

# manipulate cash
dfnc = df[df.index != 'cash']

# create variables and model
dq = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("dq", dfnc.index, cat='Integer', lowBound=0)
ab_dif_element = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("ab_dif", df.index)
mod = pulp.LpProblem("CashReduction", pulp.LpMinimize)

# objective function
mod += nav - sum([dq[i] * dfnc.loc[i, 'prccd'] + dfnc.loc[i, 'q_tilde'] * dfnc.loc[i, 'prccd'] for i in dfnc.index])

# this is redundant...you've already set lowBound
# # lower bounds:
# for i in dfnc.index:
#     mod += dq[i] >= 0

# budget constraint
mod += sum([dq[i] * dfnc.loc[i, 'prccd'] for i in dfnc.index]) <= df.loc['cash', 'val']


for i in dfnc.index:
    # pos ab_dif
    mod += ab_dif_element[i] >= dfnc.loc[i, 'w_star'] - (dq[i] * dfnc.loc[i, 'prccd'] + dfnc.loc[i, 'q_tilde'] * dfnc.loc[i, 'prccd']) / nav
    # neg ab_dif
    mod += ab_dif_element[i] >= -(dfnc.loc[i, 'w_star'] - (dq[i] * dfnc.loc[i, 'prccd'] + dfnc.loc[i, 'q_tilde'] * dfnc.loc[i, 'prccd']) / nav)

# nearer constraint
mod += sum(ab_dif_element[i] for i in dfnc.index) <= sum(df['diff_orig'])

# individual diff cannot be bigger than 3%
for i in dfnc.index:
    mod += (dfnc.loc[i, 'w_star'] -
            (dq[i] * dfnc.loc[i, 'prccd'] + dfnc.loc[i, 'q_tilde'] * dfnc.loc[i, 'prccd']) / nav) <= 0.03
for i in dfnc.index:
    mod += (dfnc.loc[i, 'w_star'] -
            (dq[i] * dfnc.loc[i, 'prccd'] + dfnc.loc[i, 'q_tilde'] * dfnc.loc[i, 'prccd']) / nav) >= -0.03

# solve model
mod.solve()

# output solution
for i in dfnc.index:
    print(i, dq[i].value(), ab_dif_element[i].value())
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I wanted to know. I just had a conceptual understanding so I learned how to implement this in algorithm. Much appreciate it!

Comment: great.  If it answered your question, you could close out the issue by hitting the check mark next to the answer.